# How to expect a plain text payload in flask-restplus?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

In order to rewrite a basic Flask example with Flask-Restplus, I would like to create a POST with only a plain text body.

The below example does what I want, but of course the documentation is not correct as I do not expect a mapping with fields, but rather the value directly.

How can I adjust the example, so that the UI Shows that I need a plain text payload (without fields)?

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api, fields

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

all_data = []


@api.route('/data')
class Data(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return jsonify(all_data)

    @api.expect(api.model("NewData", {"newdata": fields.String}))
    def post(self):
        json = request.json
        print("Adding", json)
        all_data.append(json)
        return ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

It is important that I want my data in the payload and not the URL. And while JSON input with fields might be a more solid solution, I would like to finish this version first.

(And if I go for JSON payload (not URL), is there a way to show separate input lines for the fields, such that Flask-Restplus will assemble the JSON?)

Comment: Same problem @here, this is very important if you want for instance to update a particular property  with a call like `PUT /resource/<id>/property`.